# bash : check if sum of specific words smaller than given number

Tags: bash, shell

I have 300 files consisting of this format :

```
0       0       261157  0       13267   0       314     0       274738  736485  999.999756  
1       0       261155  0       13269   0       314     0       274738  736625  1000.147705  
2       0       261162  0       13264   0       312     0       274738  736703  1000.104370  
3       0       261156  0       13265   0       312     0       274733  736838  1000.113708  
4       0       261166  0       13261   0       311     0       274738  736918  999.999756  
5       0       261173  0       13258   0       311     0       274742  737054  1000.001892  
6       0       261153  0       13284   0       311     0       274748  737137  1000.204529  
7       0       261152  0       13280   0       312     0       274744  736800  1000.188110  
8       0       261154  0       13277   0       311     0       274742  737081  1000.107178  
9       0       261150  0       13278   0       310     0       274738  737309  1000.189392  
10      2348    260942  0       13271   0       310     2348    274523  737683  1001.341980  
11      2342    260915  0       13264   0       310     2342    274489  737720  1000.341797  
12      2340    260900  0       13272   0       310     2340    274482  738490  1000.266357  
13      2339    260885  0       13284   0       309     2339    274478  738363  1000.312317
```

This is an example of a section of my files. The number of lines can range from 1000 to 50000 depending on the file.

Right now, I need to check the second column and second last column of the last line. If the sum of these numbers is smaller than 10, this implies my data has something wrong.

I know how to print out the last line by "tail", but I have never tried to extract the numbers, sum them up and compare to a number to see if it is smaller or greater.

Thanks.

Comment: Problem needs more clarification.

Comment: You should give more info on your selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tail` to extract the last line and feed it to `awk`:

```
$ tail -n 1 file | awk '$2 + $(NF-1) < 10 {print "Wrong"}'
```

In case your file has lots of rows, it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'END{x=($2+$(NF-1));if(x<10) print "Wrong";else print "correct"}' test
correct
```

Sample data used :

```
cat test

0       0       261157  0       13267   0       314     0       274738  736485  999.999756
1       0       261155  0       13269   0       314     0       274738  736625  1000.147705
2       0       261162  0       13264   0       312     0       274738  736703  1000.104370
3       0       261156  0       13265   0       312     0       274733  736838  1000.113708
4       0       261166  0       13261   0       311     0       274738  736918  999.999756
5       0       261173  0       13258   0       311     0       274742  737054  1000.001892
6       0       261153  0       13284   0       311     0       274748  737137  1000.204529
7       0       261152  0       13280   0       312     0       274744  736800  1000.188110
8       0       261154  0       13277   0       311     0       274742  737081  1000.107178
9       0       261150  0       13278   0       310     0       274738  737309  1000.189392
10      2348    260942  0       13271   0       310     2348    274523  737683  1001.341980
11      2342    260915  0       13264   0       310     2342    274489  737720  1000.341797
12      2340    260900  0       13272   0       310     2340    274482  738490  1000.266357
13      2339    260885  0       13284   0       309     2339    274478  738363  1000.312317
```

Comment: https://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_9.html#SEC95 mentions that *[POSIX] standard does not say that $0 is also preserved [inside an END rule] - - In fact, gawk does preserve the value of $0 for use in END rules. Be aware, however, that Unix awk, and possibly other implementations, do not.* I tested with `gawk`, `mawk` and `original-awk` and they all seemed preserve it.